# Polars - Failed to read delta config: Validation failed - Unknown unit 'days'

Tags: python, azure-databricks, delta-lake, python-polars

I am having some delta tables created in my azure data lake using azure databricks. I am trying to follow the below instruction, and to read them using polars.

https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.read_delta.html

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46voJ.png) of error executing `pl.read delta(table path, storage options-storage_options)`

However, it errors out. Does that mean that the transaction log is structured differently in the databricks implementation of delta?

Executing `pl.read delta(table path, storage options-storage_options)` generates exception:

```
Exception has occurred: PyDeltaTableError X
Failed to apply transaction log: Failed to read delta config: Validation failed - Unknown unit 'days
File "C:\Users\S1P967\Untitled-1.txt", line 12, in <module> pl.read_delta(table path, storage_options-storage_options)
deltalake.PyDeltaTableError: Failed to apply transaction log: Failed to read delta config: Validation failed - Unknown unit 'days'
```

Comment: What is 'days' in this case? Is it one of the partitions you read?

Comment: Could you provide a repro so we can test it out?  The thing that is a little confusing here is that if you’re reading a delta table, it shouldn’t be reading a txt file